# Trying to Launch Runescape Client - Nothing Happens

Tags: java, xfce, chromebook, client, runescape

I'm really bad at this, and this is my first experience using Ubuntu. If you don't think your answer needs to be explained, it needs to be explained as if I were three. I'm talking explicit, clear, verbatim instructions. Thank you for any and all help, especially since I'm so stupid.

I have followed [this](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343) post and downloaded Ubuntu on my HP Chromebook.
I have followed [this](http://services.runescape.com/m=rswiki/en/Linux_Native_Clients#The_RuneScape_UNIX_Client_.28RSU_Client.29) link and downloaded the Runescape client on my device.
When I check what version of java I'm running, I get this:

```
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Why is my client not running and what can I do to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

You should download the latest JDK. Do do so:

1) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

2) `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

This ppa has JDK 6/7/8/9 but 8 is the most stable as of now.

Important!!! For now, you should continue to use Java 8 because Oracle Java 9 is available as an early access release (it should be released in 2016)!